# Date range from date start to day end in PHP EST to UTC

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a database that stores dates in UTC timezone. I need to run a query to get all records with dates between the start of day of today and the end of day of today. Since the data is store in UTC and I am in EST I cannot just do y-m-d 00:00:00 to y-m-d 23:59:59  because EST is 4 hours behind UTC. How can I build this query in PHP with the correct date frame dynamically?

I also need to build a query for "last week", and "last month".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mktime works for me in most instances

```
<?php
$time = mysql_query("select time from timedata where timeID = '1'");
$row_time = mysql_fetch_assoc($time);
$convertedTime = strtotime($row_time['time']);
$hours = 4;
$NewTime = mktime(date('H',$convertedTime)-$hours,date('i',$convertedTime),date('s',$convertedTime),date('n',$convertedTime),date('j',$convertedTime),date('Y',$convertedTime);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$NewTime);
?>
```

for last week you can just take 7 off date('j') and last month take 1 off date('n')

Also be aware to set your default time zone

```
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: This helped for the week range

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the full day rage in EST like this:

```
$date_today = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', date('Y') . '-' . date('m') . '-' . date('d') . ' 00:00:00')->add(new DateInterval('PT4H'))->format('Y-m-d H:00:00');

$start = $date_today;
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', date('Y') . '-' . date('m') . '-' . date('d') . ' 00:00:00')->add(new DateInterval('PT27H'))->format('Y-m-d H:59:59');
```

I had to create today's date with time 00:00:00 then add 4 hours ( for EST)
Then for the end date I did the same but added 27 hours and 59 min 59 sec so 3 Hr 59 Mins, 59 Sec + 24 Hr (full day)